# How to modify an animated view while it is animated?

Tags: android, animation, view, listener

I tried to modify the content of a text view while it is animated, with its animation listener, with the following code:

```
final String text = [...]; 
animationGoOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        myTextView.setText(text);
        myTextView.startAnimation(animationGoIn);
    }
});
myTextView.startAnimation(animationGoOut);
```

`animationGoOut` translates the object outside of the screen and reduces its alpha to 0.
`animationGoIn` translates the object to its original position and brings its alpha to 1.
I want a TextView to go out with a text and then go in again with another text.

If I remove the instruction

```
myTextView.setText(text);
```

the animation works well, if I change the textView before the animation starts it works well too. If I change the code into the listener (as the code shows) the animation does not work at all!

Comment: I'd recommend to use the new [Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html). If you need to support API's < 11 you can check out the [Nine Old Androids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UbJhmkeSig for a nice explanation from Chet Haase about this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a TextSwitcher object.

On the layout I have a TextSwitcher (in the place where should be the TextView). Then this is my code:

```
TextSwitcher mTextSwitcher = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
    mTextSwitcher = findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
    Animation animIn = ...;
    Animation animOut = ...;
    mTextSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    mTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(animIn);
    mTextSwitcher.setOutAnimation(animOut);
}

private void changeText(String nextText) {
    mTextSwitcher.setText(nextText);
}

@Override
public View makeView() {
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);  // the size of a LargeText text view
    return t;
}
```

Each time I call mTextSwitcher.setText(String) it performs the out animation and then the in animation with the new text. Exactly what I wanted!